# Java Robot mouseMove script not closing

Tags: java

I grabbed and modified some code below to move the mouse for every minute called. Using eclipse to run this code if I enter say timeTest(10) and tell the script to stop running after 3 minutes, it won't stop until the 10 minutes are up. Its like something is still open.

```
public void timeTest(int i) throws AWTException {
    Robot hal = new Robot();
    Random random = new Random();

    int count=0;

    while(count < i){
        hal.delay(60000);//wait 1 minute

        int x = random.nextInt() % 640;
        int y = random.nextInt() % 480;

        hal.mouseMove(x,y);

        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's going on in your `delay()` method? What is the value of `i` in your example?

Comment: How are you telling the program to stop? I'm assuming robot has it's own thread it runs on. This complicates the stopping of the program if not done properly.

Comment: MarsAtomic i was messing with that to get it to equal a minute, I guess I can just change it to 60,000. The int I is how many minutes I want the script to keep moving the mouse. Tim Hunter the eclipse client I am using is wrapping the automated testing tool Rational Functional tester